# AccessDeniedException: Cognito_tpnpoolUnauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, ssm

Lambda function get the password from  SSM Password store but encounter this error.
Already set up the policy on both lambda role and cognito role.
ssm:Describeparameters
ssm:Getparameter
sts:assumerole

*{ AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::000008109xxx:assumed-role/Cognito_tpnpoolUnauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:ap-southeast-1
:000008109xxx:parameter/TPN_SFX_P01_Pass
    at Request.extractError (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\json.js:48:27)
    at Request.callListeners (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request. (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
    at Request. (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:115:18)
  message: 'User: arn:aws:sts::000008109xxx:assumed-role/Cognito_tpnpoolUnauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:ap-southeast-1:000008109xxx
:parameter/xxx_SFX_P01_Pass',
  code: 'AccessDeniedException',
  time: 2018-08-03T07:17:50.976Z,
  requestId: 'cec59419-24cd-427e-99dc-b1f3495f0ceb',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
*